# How to allow page interaction while Bootstrap modal active?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a modal backdrop in place to prevent user from interacting with the page while the modal is active.

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="false" id="calibration_modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Although I would like to allow the user to click the navigation bar and go to another page without closing the modal, while still blocking the other elements of the page.

Is it possible? (I am using bootstrap 5)

Comment: What's in the modal that it can't be easily dismissed? Your UX is somewhat non-standard.

Comment: I don't see any way to do that solely using Bootstrap's API(docs) so I'm guessing you would manually need to do that.

Comment: @isherwood I dont allow dismissing because it is performing an operation on a device that it should either cancel the operation or move to another page. Dismissing is not wanted here.

Comment: @Aryan3212 I am willing to try. Any idea how?

Comment: So cancel the operation on modal close.

Comment: I think you're asking a bit of an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info). Stick to conventional UI mechanisms and shift your code to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with JavaScript only, Bootstrap doesn't seem to give any external API for it.

What happens is that whenever a modal is activated(i.e. button clicked) an overlay covers all elements of the page, so the elements are beneath that translucent overlay so they are unreachable and therefore, unclickable.

What we can do however is make the navigation bar "higher" than the modal by adding a z-index attribute to its stylesheet. See below, that the Bootstrap modal has a value of 1060.

[image: Bootstrap z-index modal CSS]

TLDR: Use a z-index value of greater than 1060 for your navigation bar. So it'll always be on top. BUT be sure to also push the modal downwards by tinkering with the margins/positions in YOUR CSS files. Since, the navbar and modal may overlap.

```js
var modalToggle = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('staticBackdrop'));
modalToggle.show();
```

```css
.modal-dialog.dropped {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1200;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog dropped">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This was my first attempt. It does not work. The navbar does become clear of the backdrop and is normally visible but the modal prevent the user to click in any of the navigation items.

Comment: This will work if you do it right. You can't expect us to sort every detail of a site we can't see. If you were to create a demo in your question we could help more.